# Как в цикле пройти по однотипным элементам?

Tags: java, android

```
public void clickCount(View v) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        EditText inputgram = findViewById(R.id.grammin1);
    }
}
```

У меня элементов текстовое поле довольно много, к ним нужно применить одинаковые действия при нажатии на кнопку, называются они однотипно:  grammin1 до grammin50.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596311/java-android-arraylist-with-id

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596361/3656904) ответа.

Можно использовать методы `Context.getResources()`и `Resources.getResourceIdentifier()` для получения идентификатора.

Пример:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
    int resourceIdentifier = this.getResources().getResourceIdentifier("input_" + i);
    EditText input_i = (EditText) findViewById(resourceIdentifier, "id", this.getPackageName()));
}
```